# When using multiple GPUs, Tensorflow ExponentialMovingAverage is not suitable for batch normalization?

Tags: tensorflow, moving-average, multi-gpu, batch-normalization

Recently, I have tried to use multiple GPUs to speed up training. But I have some problems with Batch normalization. Specifically, when I use [ExponentialMovingAverage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage) to get averaged batch mean and variation, the accuracy is bad.

I have tried several ways (functions) to implement batch normalization as follows. The rest parts of the code are the same, I just tried different batch normalization functions. When using 2 GPUs, Methods 2-4 work well, but the accuracy of method 1 on test data set is really bad. When I switch to using just 1 GPU, all methods work well.

Data set is CIFAR10, batch size is 128. When using 2 GPUs, each GPU deals with 64 samples, and then averaging the gradients from each GPUs, just like the tensorflow tutorial [CIFAR10 multi-gpu](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L110).

My tensorflow version is 1.1.0, python version is 2.7 and OS is ubuntu 16.04.
CUDA version is 7.5.17.

My question is why using tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage (method 1) works so bad when using multiple GPUs? I am really confused.

Method 1:

```
def batch_norm_conv(x, n_out = 3, phase_train=True, scope='bn_conv'):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope):
        beta = tf.get_variable('beta_conv', shape=[n_out], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        gamma = tf.get_variable('gamma_conv', shape=[n_out], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0))

        batch_mean_temp, batch_var_temp = tf.nn.moments(x, [0,1,2], name='moments')
        batch_mean = tf.get_variable('batch_mean', shape=batch_mean_temp.get_shape(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
        batch_var = tf.get_variable('batch_var', shape=batch_var_temp.get_shape(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)

        mean_op = tf.assign(batch_mean, batch_mean_temp)
        var_op = tf.assign(batch_var, batch_var_temp)

        ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.5, zero_debias=False)
        ema_apply_op = ema.apply([batch_mean, batch_var])
        def mean_var_with_update():
            with tf.control_dependencies([mean_op, var_op]):
                with tf.control_dependencies([ema_apply_op]):
                    return tf.identity(batch_mean), tf.identity(batch_var)

        mean, var = tf.cond(phase_train,
                        mean_var_with_update,
                        lambda: (ema.average(batch_mean), ema.average(batch_var)))    
        normed = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, mean, var, beta, gamma, 1e-5)
    return normed
```

Method 2:

```
def batch_norm_conv(x, n_out = 3, phase_train=True, scope='bn_conv'):
  with tf.variable_scope(scope):
      beta = tf.get_variable('beta_conv', shape=[n_out], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
      gamma = tf.get_variable('gamma_conv', shape=[n_out], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0))

      batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0,1,2], name='moments')
      print(batch_mean.get_shape())
      mean_average = tf.get_variable('mean_average', shape=batch_mean.get_shape(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
      var_average = tf.get_variable('var_average', shape=batch_var.get_shape(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

      decay=0.5
      def mean_var_with_update():  
          mean_temp = decay * mean_average + (1-decay) * batch_mean
          var_temp = decay * var_average + (1-decay) * batch_var
          mean_op = tf.assign(mean_average, mean_temp)
          var_op = tf.assign(var_average, var_temp)
          with tf.control_dependencies([mean_op, var_op]):
              return tf.identity(batch_mean), tf.identity(batch_var)

      mean, var = tf.cond(phase_train, mean_var_with_update, lambda: (mean_average, var_average))
      normed = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, mean, var, beta, gamma, 1e-3)
  return normed
```

Method 3:

```
from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages

def batch_norm_conv(x, n_out = 3, phase_train=True, scope='bn_conv'):

  with tf.variable_scope(scope):
      beta = tf.get_variable('beta_conv', shape=[n_out], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
      gamma = tf.get_variable('gamma_conv', shape=[n_out], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0))

      batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0,1,2], name='moments')

      moving_mean = tf.get_variable('batch_mean', shape=batch_mean.get_shape(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
      moving_variance = tf.get_variable('batch_var', shape=batch_var.get_shape(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)

      update_moving_mean = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(moving_mean,
                                                                 batch_mean, 0.5, zero_debias=False)
      update_moving_variance = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(
                                                          moving_variance, batch_var, 0.5, zero_debias=False)
      def mean_var_with_update():
          with tf.control_dependencies([update_moving_mean, update_moving_variance]):
                  return tf.identity(batch_mean), tf.identity(batch_var)

      mean, var = tf.cond(phase_train, 
                                        mean_var_with_update,
                                        lambda: (moving_mean, moving_variance))

      normed = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, mean, var, beta, gamma, 1e-3)
  return normed
```

Method 4:

```
def batch_norm_conv(x， phase_train=True, scope='bn_conv'):

  with tf.variable_scope(scope):
      normed = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x, 
                                            center=True, 
                                            scale=True, 
                                            is_training = phase_train,
                                            decay = 0.5,
                                            trainable = True
                                           )

  return normed
```

Results for method 1:

```
('epoch', 0, 'test accuracy:', 0.12970000132918358)
('epoch', 1, 'test accuracy:', 0.20419999957084656)
('epoch', 2, 'test accuracy:', 0.11649999991059304)
('epoch', 3, 'test accuracy:', 0.12790000066161156)
('epoch', 4, 'test accuracy:', 0.17040000036358832)
('epoch', 5, 'test accuracy:', 0.15139999836683274)
('epoch', 6, 'test accuracy:', 0.13050000220537186)
('epoch', 7, 'test accuracy:', 0.15879999995231628)
('epoch', 8, 'test accuracy:', 0.17370000183582307)
('epoch', 9, 'test accuracy:', 0.17910000011324884)
('epoch', 10, 'test accuracy:', 0.17960000038146973)
('epoch', 11, 'test accuracy:', 0.12400000095367432)
('epoch', 12, 'test accuracy:', 0.13669999763369561)
('epoch', 13, 'test accuracy:', 0.25510000437498093)
('epoch', 14, 'test accuracy:', 0.18769999742507934)
('epoch', 15, 'test accuracy:', 0.16730000004172324)
('epoch', 16, 'test accuracy:', 0.15510000288486481)
('epoch', 17, 'test accuracy:', 0.19639999866485597)
('epoch', 18, 'test accuracy:', 0.24789999574422836)
('epoch', 19, 'test accuracy:', 0.15929999947547913)
('epoch', 20, 'test accuracy:', 0.17439999729394912)
```

Results for method 2 - 4 (they have no big difference, so just post one of them):

```
('epoch', 0, 'test accuracy:', 0.27250000238418581)
('epoch', 1, 'test accuracy:', 0.42709999978542329)
('epoch', 2, 'test accuracy:', 0.50179999470710757)
('epoch', 3, 'test accuracy:', 0.56709998846054077)
('epoch', 4, 'test accuracy:', 0.59760001301765442)
('epoch', 5, 'test accuracy:', 0.66010000705718996)
('epoch', 6, 'test accuracy:', 0.65400000214576726)
('epoch', 7, 'test accuracy:', 0.69880000352859495)
('epoch', 8, 'test accuracy:', 0.69749999642372129)
('epoch', 9, 'test accuracy:', 0.71029999256134035)
('epoch', 10, 'test accuracy:', 0.72619999051094053)
('epoch', 11, 'test accuracy:', 0.72920000553131104)
('epoch', 12, 'test accuracy:', 0.7372000098228455)
('epoch', 13, 'test accuracy:', 0.75380001068115232)
('epoch', 14, 'test accuracy:', 0.74269998073577881)
('epoch', 15, 'test accuracy:', 0.76199999451637268)
('epoch', 16, 'test accuracy:', 0.7636999785900116)
('epoch', 17, 'test accuracy:', 0.76039999723434448)
('epoch', 18, 'test accuracy:', 0.77150000333786006)
('epoch', 19, 'test accuracy:', 0.77920001149177553)
('epoch', 20, 'test accuracy:', 0.79100000858306885)
```

Comment: Did `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` not work for you? Also note that you can generally speed it up by setting the `fused` parameter to `True`.

Comment: tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm works, which is actually method 4.

Comment: @bcxiao: Do you solve the problem of method 4 for training the BN in multiple GPU? Thanks

Comment: Yes, no problem with method 4.